# How does the Auto selection work?

Tags: pikmin-bloom

When choosing Pikmin to send on an expedition, there's an "Auto" option that will automatically select a party to send.  This feature doesn't seem to work how I would expect, though.  For example, it doesn't select optimal choices when attacking a mushroom (optimal being same color and highest friendship).  Is there any reasoning behind the selections made by the Auto feature?